# sqoop vs hdfs commands

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am a new bie to Sqoop. As per my understanding, Sqoop commands are for importing data from database like MySql to HDFs and viceversa and HDFS commands are for dealing with data in HDFS, such as getting data from HDFS to local file system and viceversa. Cant we use sqoop commands to deal with data in HDFS - to get the data from local file system to hdfs and viceversa. Please let me know the exact differences between Sqoop and HDFS commands. Why do we have two separate things. Why they did not put all these commands into one set. Apologies, if my question does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop commands serves below purposes:
1)Import/export data from any database to hdfs/hive/hbase and vice versa. Its not restrict only to hdfs import and export.
2)data can be sqooped at one go if we need to move a whole database/list of tables.
3)only incremental data can be imported via sqoop commands.
4) It also required connection driver to connect to databases
In short it deals with tables/databases.

hdfs commands:
1) It only used to transfer any type(csv,text,xls) of file from local to hdfs or vice versa. Its just serve basic functionality of moving or copying data from one system to other just like unix commands.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop only functionality to import and export data from RDBMS (Structured) to Hadoop. It does not provide any other HDFS inside activities. Once if you get the data using Sqoop to HDFS, HDFS commands will be used to process the data (copy, move,etc)

For more Sqoop functionalities http://hortonworks.com/apache/sqoop/

Answer (score 0):

Yes your understanding is correct.

Sqoop commands are for :

importing data from any relational database(like mysql) to HDFS/Hive/Hbase

exporting data from HDFS/Hive/Hbase to any relational database(like mysql)

hdfs commands are for :

Copying/transferring any files (like :.txt,.csv,.xls,..etc) from local to hdfs or vice versa.

for :

Why do we have two separate things. Why they did not put all these commands into one set.

answer :

Sqoop commands
(for copying structured data b/w two different systems)

Hdfs commands
(for copying files b/w local and hdfs)

using sqoop we cannot copy files from local to hdfs and viceversa

and also

using hdfs commands we cannot copy data from hdfs to any other external databases (like mysql) and viceversa.